# Can JVM trust a self-signed certificate for only a single run?

Tags: java, ssl, clojure, jvm, self-signed

I am trying to get a clojure jar to trust a self-signed certificate that I made when I run the jar, only I don't actually want to add the cert to my certificate store. Is there any way to get the JVM to trust this openssl self-signed cert ephemerally, or in a way that it will only be trusted for a single run?

If there is an in-language way to do it, and if it helps, I'm using the [clj-http-lite](https://github.com/martinklepsch/clj-http-lite) library, using the `get` function. Extra points, though, for a generic JVM-wide solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not recommend to override global trust store using command line argument `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` for JVM. Instead, if you need to connect to remote server using self-signed certificate, I recommend to build SSL context in code and use it for connection. This approach is better when you don't want to downgrade global JVM security and if you have multiple endpoints each requires self-signed certificate for connection.

Here is example of [Building SSL context](https://gist.github.com/mikeananev/76346532933bd9ff108ccbb04a89b849) which can be used in http/get function. You can pass it to `request` function (see code for insecure? option and make the same way).

Comment: My vote is locked, i voted this down but it turns out I need an in-language way of doing this too for unit testing purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a (temporary) *trust store* and configure it on the command line with `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` system properties: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/adminguide/cadminsslclient.html